# Is it safe to use 2 PSUs, where one PSU provides power for 2 GPUs, and the other provides for 1 GPU and the motherboard?

Tags: power-supply, power, gpu

I have 3 GPUs and 2 power supplies. None of the PSUs are strong enough to power all the GPUs, but they would provide enough power if I connect 2 GPUs to one of them, and one GPU and the motherboard to the other. Would this be safe?

Comment: How would you power on both PSU's?

Comment: by connecting them to power outlets in my wall and turning the power on? Your comment makes me suspect i'm lacking some crucial knowledge

Comment: The button you press on your computer to turn it on is a small switch that connects to the mother board. The mother board is hooked in to the PSU via a (usually) 24-pin connector that gets "shorted" which then connects the inner circuits of the PSU to "power up". Without a mother board connected to the PSU, the only way to "power up" the PSU is to short out the main-line on the 24-pin connector, which requires a few circuits (i.e. a resistor, etc.) to ensure you don't fry the PSU ...

Comment: all my components are out in the open, i touch some wires together to power on the motherboard after flipping a switch on the power supply that's connected to both the motherboard and 1 gpu. what i want to do is to connect two more GPUs to a second power supply, which would not be connected to the motherboard.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0OKmIuNtmI